# How do I transfer a variable between Activities?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, transmission

I have a code that transmits values over bluetooth
There are two activities in it. I need to make sure that the bluetoothController variable is passed to another activity and I can also transfer values from the second activity.

Firts activity

```
package com.example.bluetoothmodule2

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.SeekBar
import androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.bluetoothmodule2.databinding.FragmentMainBinding
import com.example.bt_def.BluetoothConstants
import com.example.bt_def.bluetooth.BluetoothController

class MainFragment : Fragment(), BluetoothController.Listener{
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentMainBinding
    private lateinit var bluetoothController: BluetoothController
    private lateinit var btAdapter: BluetoothAdapter
    private var rm = 0   // руль
    private var gm = 0   // газ
    private var dm= 0   // коробка передач
    private var hm = 0   // сигнал

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initBtAdapter()
        val pref = activity?.getSharedPreferences(
            BluetoothConstants.PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        )
        val mac = pref?.getString(BluetoothConstants.MAC, "")
        bluetoothController = BluetoothController(btAdapter)
        binding.bList.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_deviceListFragment)
        }
       binding.Villas.setOnClickListener {
           findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_villasFragment)
    }
        binding.Starter.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_startFragment)
        }
        binding.bConnect.setOnClickListener {
            bluetoothController.connect(mac ?: "", this)
        }


        binding.RSend.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener { // Слайдер для руля
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                rm = progress
                binding.textR.text = "Руль: $rm"
                bluetoothController.sendMessage("rm=${rm};")
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {

            }
        })

        binding.GSend.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{ //Слайдер для газа
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                gm = progress
                binding.textG.text = "Газ: $gm"
                bluetoothController.sendMessage("gm=${gm};")
            }


            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {

            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
            }

        })


        binding.VSend.setOnClickListener {
            dm = 1
            bluetoothController.sendMessage("dm=${dm};")
        }
        binding.NSend.setOnClickListener {
            dm = 0
            bluetoothController.sendMessage("dm=${dm};")
        }
        binding.BSend.setOnClickListener {
            dm = 2
            bluetoothController.sendMessage("dm=${dm};")
        }
        binding.SSend.setOnClickListener {
            hm = 1
            bluetoothController.sendMessage("hm=${hm};")
        }
        binding.R0.setOnClickListener {
            binding.RSend.progress = 0
            bluetoothController.sendMessage("rm=${rm};")
        }
    }




    private fun initBtAdapter() {
        val bManager = activity?.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as
                BluetoothManager
        btAdapter = bManager.adapter
    }

    override fun onReceive(message: String) {
        activity?.runOnUiThread {
            when (message) {
                BluetoothController.BLUETOOTH_CONNECTED -> {
                    binding.bConnect.backgroundTintList = AppCompatResources
                        .getColorStateList(requireContext(), R.color.red)
                    binding.bConnect.text = "Disconnect"
                }

                BluetoothController.BLUETOOTH_NO_CONNECTED -> {
                    binding.bConnect.backgroundTintList = AppCompatResources
                        .getColorStateList(requireContext(), R.color.green)
                    binding.bConnect.text = "Connect"
                }

                else -> {
                    binding.tvStatus.text = message
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second activity

```
package com.example.bluetoothmodule2

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.SeekBar
import com.example.bluetoothmodule2.databinding.FragmentVillasBinding
import com.example.bt_def.BluetoothConstants
import com.example.bt_def.bluetooth.BluetoothController

private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

class VillasFragment : Fragment(), BluetoothController.Listener{
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentVillasBinding
    private lateinit var bluetoothController: BluetoothController
    private lateinit var btAdapter: BluetoothAdapter
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null
    private var vt = 0 // тормоз вилы
    private var gt = 0 // газ вилы
    private var ut = 0 // Вверх/Вниз вилы
    private var ft = 0 // От себя/К себе

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        binding = FragmentVillasBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initBtAdapter()
        val pref = activity?.getSharedPreferences(
            BluetoothConstants.PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        )
        val mac = pref?.getString(BluetoothConstants.MAC, "")
        bluetoothController = BluetoothController(btAdapter)
        bluetoothController.connect(mac ?: "", this)


        binding.TVillas.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener { // Слайдер для руля
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                vt = progress
                binding.Ttext.text = "Тормоз: $vt"
                bluetoothController.sendMessage("vt=${vt};")
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {

            }
        })

        binding.GVillas.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener { // Слайдер для руля
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                gt = progress
                binding.Gtext.text = "Газ: $gt"
                bluetoothController.sendMessage("gt=${gt};")
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {

            }
        })

        binding.UDVillas.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener { // Слайдер для руля
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                 ut = progress
                binding.UpDownText.text = "Вверх/Вниз: $ut"
                bluetoothController.sendMessage("ut=${ut};")
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {

            }
        })

        binding.FTVillas.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener { // Слайдер для руля
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                ft = progress
                binding.FromMtoMText.text = "От себя/К себе: $ft"
                bluetoothController.sendMessage("ft=${ft};")
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {

            }
        })
    }

    companion object {

        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            VillasFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }

    private fun initBtAdapter() {
        val bManager = activity?.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as
                BluetoothManager
        btAdapter = bManager.adapter
    }

    override fun onReceive(message: String) {
    }
}
```

I tried to do the same as in the first activity, but when switching to the second activity, the Bluetooth connection breaks

Comment: Why not create a service inside of a ViewModel that interacts with Bluetooth and have the two activities use it?

Answer (score 0):

To pass data

```
val intent = Intent(activity?, activity2::class.java)
intent.putExtra("value name","value want to trasfer")
startActivity(intent)
```

To recieve data

```
var value = getStrinExtra("data")
\\if you transfer an integer use getIntExtra instead of getStringExtra
```